# Tensorflow / Deepdream InvalidArgumentError Argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-dream

Im using this TensorFlow resource to create a deep dream image (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/deepdream), but instead of InceptionV3 I'm loading in my own convolutional neural net (model summary at the bottom). Instead of their "mixed3" and "mixed5" layers, I use my "conv2d_40" and "conv2d_41" layers. When I run the "run_deep_dream_simple" step using my model's layers, I get an `InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:` Argument saying:

> Inputs to operation
> while/body/_1/gradient_tape/while/model_1/conv2d_41/ReluGrad of type
> ReluGrad must have the same size and shape.  Input 0: [1,213,141,64]
> != input 1: [1,87,157,64]      [[{{node
> gradient_tape/while/model_1/conv2d_41/ReluGrad}}]]
> [Op:__inference___call___8564]

It seems like I need to change a tensor shape or deprocess the image I'm feeding into it, which is (180, 320, 3). Any ideas for how to do this?

Model Summary:

```
 Layer (type):
 conv2d_40 (Conv2D)          (None, 430, 286, 32)      896       
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_53 (Bat  (None, 430, 286, 32)     128       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_40 (MaxPoolin  (None, 215, 143, 32)     0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 dropout_53 (Dropout)        (None, 215, 143, 32)      0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_41 (Conv2D)          (None, 213, 141, 64)      18496     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_54 (Bat  (None, 213, 141, 64)     256       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_41 (MaxPoolin  (None, 106, 70, 64)      0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 dropout_54 (Dropout)        (None, 106, 70, 64)       0         
                                                                 
 conv2d_42 (Conv2D)          (None, 104, 68, 128)      73856     
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_55 (Bat  (None, 104, 68, 128)     512       
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_42 (MaxPoolin  (None, 52, 34, 128)      0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 dropout_55 (Dropout)        (None, 52, 34, 128)       0         
                                                                 
 flatten_14 (Flatten)        (None, 226304)            0         
                                                                 
 dense_27 (Dense)            (None, 512)               115868160 
                                                                 
 batch_normalization_56 (Bat  (None, 512)              2048      
 chNormalization)                                                
                                                                 
 dropout_56 (Dropout)        (None, 512)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_28 (Dense)            (None, 2)                 1026
```